# jQuery .css display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do the following:

- I have 6 div. Inside each div is another div with display:none.

I want to do in jQuery when i click on each div all 6 div change to display:none and the div inside the div clicked to show in the screen.

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Weinz/xaMfk/2/

The only thing that happen it's all goes display:none

What can i do? I try also with show and hide and doesn't work

Thank you in advance

Comment: Tip: You can't hide a parent element without hiding the child.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that. Going to try again.

Comment: when you hide the parent, the child will automatically be hidden aswel.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/Weinz/xaMfk/10 This is how i make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you got your answer above.  @Zoltan's approach looks like it could work for you.  I would also consider maybe adding classes to the divs as it would reduce the jquery and css.

```
<div class="outerDiv" id="box1">Box1</div>
<div id="cont1" class="innerDiv" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div>
<div class="outerDiv" id="box2">Box2</div>
<div id="cont2" class="innerDiv" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div>
<div class="outerDiv" id="box3">Box3</div>
<div id="cont3" class="innerDiv" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div>    
<div class="outerDiv" id="box4">Box4</div>
<div id="cont4" class="innerDiv" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div>
<div class="outerDiv" id="box5">Box5</div>
<div id="cont5" class="innerDiv" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div>



$(function() {
    $(".outerDiv").click(function() {
        $(".outerDiv").hide();
        $(".innerDiv").hide();
        $(this).next("div").show();
    });
});​
.outerDiv{border: 1px solid;}​ 
div,div p {display:inline;}
```

Comment: My mistake but i only want to show the div id="cont1" if i click box1 and so on with next boxes. Your code show me every "cont" div

Comment: did you end up using this or just keeping what you had?

Comment: I did end up using your fiddle but with new additions check it out 
http://jsfiddle.net/Weinz/jdFRw/4/

Comment: A lot less code eh?  looks good...glad it's working for you.  Much appreciate if you could mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="box1" class="outer">Box1<div id="cont1" class="inner" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box2" class="outer">Box2<div id="cont2" class="inner" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box3" class="outer">Box3<div id="cont3" class="inner" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
```

---

```
$(function(){
    $(".outer").click(function(){  
        var id= this.id;
        $("#"+id+" .inner").show(); 
//user toggle instead of show if you need toggle

   });

});
```

This code will hep you, if you are intened to show each hidden div when a user clicks parent div. **If you hide parent div, then the inner content will also be hidden.**

Answer (score 1):

[Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8g3cf/)

As I understand your question this is what you need.

JS

```
$(function(){
   $("#wrapper").on('click', 'div.maindiv',function(){
       $(this).find('div.innerdiv').show();
       $(this).siblings('div.maindiv').hide();

   });
});
```

This will show whatever the inner div content of the div you clicked and will hide the other divs on the same element level. **Don't forget to try the demo out** and give the feedback.(***link is given at the beginning of the answer***)

Hope this will solve your problem. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks.

Comment: I need to hide also the "box1" when i click on it. When i click a box i want to hide all "boxes" and show it's child div. But you guys told me if the parent is hide the child is hidden too

Comment: yes it is. It is not possible to show the child div if we are to hide the parent div. Parent div must be shown

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaMfk/3/):

```
// HTML:
<div id="box1">Box1<div id="cont1" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box2">Box2<div id="cont2" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box3">Box3<div id="cont3" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box4">Box4<div id="cont4" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>
<div id="box5">Box5<div id="cont5" style="display:none"><p>Some text and img</p></div></div>

// CSS:
div {
    display:inline;
}
#box1 {border: 1px solid;}
#box2 {border: 1px solid;}
#box3 {border: 1px solid;}
#box4 {border: 1px solid;}
#box5 {border: 1px solid;}

// JS:
$(function(){
   $("#box1").click(function(){
       $(this).css("display","");
       //$("#box1").css("display","none");
       $("#box2").css("display","none");
       $("#box3").css("display","none");
       $("#box4").css("display","none");
       $("#box5").css("display","none");
   });
});
```